# Change Logo on 'Allow Access' Page

Tags: grant-login-access

Does anyone know how to change the logo that is getting shown right above the 'Allow Access?' text? Is it a file or a document? Where is the logo image getting pulled from?

[image: Allow Access Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logo can be only changed in Salesforce Environment where connected app has been created (same place where you can peek to Connected App Key or Secret).

Given option is located in Connected App Settings, it can be found under following path:

- **Classic**: Setup -> Create -> Apps -> Scroll to Connected App -> Select desired one -> Edit
- **Lightning**: Setup -> Apps -> App Manager -> Select Connected App -> Edit

**Example**:
[image]

**Documentation (thanks to @sfdcfox):**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5

Comment: Related documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you @kurunve BUT when I go to Connected App page in **Classic** there is nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Seyitbek do you see your app as inn list here -- https://imgur.com/a/h07FxFI?

Comment: On that page under "Connected Apps" nothing shows, it's blank.

Comment: Well, then you have created that app in different salesforce environment (org) or on sandbox

Comment: you were right! I should have been checking in our business org, not our packaging or coding org! Thank you @kurunve.